# what does "return list == NULL ? 0 : list->value + fun(list->next)" do?

Tags: c, operators

I'm a beginner in programming and while studying lists in C I found this function and don't know what it does. Can someone explain please.

```
int fun(list_t *list) {
    return list == NULL ? 0 : list->value + fun(list->next);
}
```

I think its a shorter if else statement for

```
if (list == NULL)
     return 0;
else {
     return list->value;
     fun(list->next);
}
```

Is this right or am I misreading it?

Comment: Partly right - if `list != NULL` the sum of `list->value + fun(list->next)` will be returned.

Comment: In you 2nd snippet `fun(list->next);` will never get called due the `return`statement in the line before.

Comment: For your reference: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `? :` is called the [Conditional (ternary) operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/14631/):

```
return list == NULL ? 0 : list->value + fun(list->next);
```

Is the same as:

```
if(list == NULL) {
    return 0;
}
else {
    return list->value + fun(list->next);
}
```

Or more clearly:

```
return (list->value + fun(list->next));
```

The sum will be evaluated first, and the result is returned.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer already answer your question. I just want to note a difference: ternary operator can be used to **return a value**

```
if(cond)
   str = "foo";
else 
   str = "bar";
```

Using ternary, you can write:

```
str = cond ? "foo" : "bar";
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is correct.
In this code they have used Linked List, Pointer and most important they have used conditional or ternary operator.

In function fun(list_t *list) they used conditional operator.
Syntax     :        (Condition? true_value: false_value);

return list == NULL ? 0 : list->value + fun(list->next);

Here NULL represent the condition, 0 represent the true part and list->value + fun(list->next) represent the false part.
Finally true or false value will be stored in variable list and it is returned.

Answer (score 0):

They have used conditional or ternary operator.

In function `fun(list_t *list)` they used conditional operator.

`Syntax  :  (Condition? true_value: false_value);`

`return list == NULL ? 0 : list->value + fun(list->next);`

Here `list==NULL` represent the condition to be checked ,`0` represent the true part and

`list->value + fun(list->next)` represent the false part.

Finally depending on the condition evaluation true or false value will be returned to the calling function.

if the `list==NULL` is true

`0` will be returned

If it is false i.e `list==NULL` is false, then the  `list->value` is return plus it will make a recursive call to the

`fun(list->next)`.